# Using real AdMob ads in alpha/beta testing

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, mobile-ad-mediation

My android application has some admob ads. I am testing my admob in Google Play store Alpha & Beta channel.

My question is:

**Can I use REAL admob ad unit ids when I deploy my app into Google play
store Alpha & Beta channels? Does it violate google play policy? What
if i click or don't click them?**

I read this in Google admob:

> Do I need to use test ads? Yes. It is against AdMob policy to use live
>   ads during development, and doing so could cause the suspension of
>   your AdMob account.

BUT it seems not very clear to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I use REAL admob ad unit ids when I deploy my app into Google play
>   store Alpha & Beta channels?

Yes, you can, it does not violate the policy.

> What if i click or don't click them?

You cannot/should not click on your own live ads.

(well technically you can, but you will get suspended for it)

Comment: If the app is in the store why shouldn't be clicked?

Comment: @user3290180 it's against Google's policy to click your own live ads

Comment: I know it's forbidden while developing, but on the store you're like any other user.

Comment: @user3290180 If it's your app, you could deliberately click your own ads repeatedly. All you would have to do is click your own ads all day and make tons of money by exploiting the system. This is not something Google would allow.

Comment: Beware of Pre-launch report - your account may get suspended! See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 24):

Technically you can, **but** there is one very important point to consider - Pre-launch report. You need to either have Pre-launch reports disabled, or make sure you don't show ads to Firebase test devices, or else you will get a bunch of "clicks by bots", with all the consequences.

I just got my account suspended for a month by accidently doing this - don't repeat my mistake.

You can disable Pre-launch reports in Play Console settings (see screenshot), or use this function to somehow hide your ads from testing devices:

```
boolean isTestDevice() {
    return Boolean.valueOf(Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "firebase.test.lab"));
}
```

**More info in [this article on ubuverse.com](https://ubuverse.com/using-admob-in-your-android-app-beware-of-the-pre-launch-report/)**

**Firebase official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for)**

[image: Google Play Console settings]

Answer (score 0):

If you can get Device ID's of testing devices. Please add them to request. That is best approach.

```
// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();
```

Comment: Check my answer above. Using this approach will not let you safely upload your app to alpha/beta. I had this in from the start and still got my account suspended for a month. And if you know a way to get IDs of Firebase test devices, please share.